# How to manage cookies in SAP CDC application for authentication

Tags: authorization, jmeter-5.0, unauthorized, gigya

I have added http cookie manager. Still getting error message:

> unauthorised user

I have also changed the property in `user.properties` file:

```
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
```

What to know about how to manage the authenticity?

From where we get the cookies related to authentication and how to manage that in requests?